# Looking for a solution to migrate excel app

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for a php based solution to shift from old style excel app. Here are my requirements.

Looking for a php driven paid / opensource solution, which provided similar interface like excel. Idea is not to train users again or need minimum training time.

I can deploy on my own premises. Google sheet does not provide on-premises solution.

Prefered if it work without any framework in agnostic mode. Idea is to avoid framework fat.

Able to integrate with other DBMS applications, fetching records etc.

Thanks.